# Get the group by on 2 column and date as latest

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 table and I m fetching record as below

[image]

The query is as

```
Select   BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code,
         BMC.JCRS_Mem_Description,
         BMC.JCRS_Mem_Date,
         BJCM.JCRS_Mast_Title
From     Bus_MemberCourse BMC
Inner Join Bus_JourneymanCourseMaster BJCM
    On BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code = BJCM.JCRS_Mast_Code
Where    BMC.JCRS_Mem_Completed = 1
         And BMC.JCRS_Mem_mem_ID = 5010
Group By BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code,
         BMC.JCRS_Mem_Description,
         BMC.JCRS_Mem_Date,
         BJCM.JCRS_Mast_Title
```

But what I want is I need to make group by on Jcrs_mem_crs_code and Jcrs_mem_description and if this 2 column data are common then I want to took the latest date only from this multiple dates. i.e. I want to pick only that row and ignore the other rows.

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server 2012` or `SQL Server 2008 R2`?  Pick one.

Comment: @Siyual This query can be run in both, correct?. Thanks for formatting

Comment: @Xtremcool Yeah but 2012 introduced a lot of useful functions that 2008 doesn't have.  The version limits or expands the possible answers.

Comment: @AaronDietz ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want `MAX(date)`:

```
Select   BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code,
         BMC.JCRS_Mem_Description,
         MAX(BMC.JCRS_Mem_Date) as JCRS_Mem_Date,
         BJCM.JCRS_Mast_Title
From     Bus_MemberCourse BMC
Inner Join Bus_JourneymanCourseMaster BJCM
    On BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code = BJCM.JCRS_Mast_Code
Where BMC.JCRS_Mem_Completed = 1
And   BMC.JCRS_Mem_mem_ID = 5010
Group By BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code,
         BMC.JCRS_Mem_Description,
         BJCM.JCRS_Mast_Title
```

Comment: Its Working great

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `Group by` at all (you aren't doing any aggregation in your query).

This can easily be done with a `Row_Number()` windowed function with a `Partition` on those two columns whilst ordering by the date:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select   BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code,
             BMC.JCRS_Mem_Description,
             BMC.JCRS_Mem_Date,
             BJCM.JCRS_Mast_Title,
             Row_Number() Over (Partition By BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code,
                                             BMC.JCRS_Mem_Description
                                Order By     BMC.JCRS_Mem_Date Desc) As RN
    From     Bus_MemberCourse BMC
    Inner Join Bus_JourneymanCourseMaster BJCM
        On BMC.JCRS_Mem_crs_Code = BJCM.JCRS_Mast_Code
    Where    BMC.JCRS_Mem_Completed = 1
             And BMC.JCRS_Mem_mem_ID = 5010
)
Select  JCRS_Mem_crs_Code,
        JCRS_Mem_Description,
        JCRS_Mem_Date,
        JCRS_Mast_Title
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```